# what's the exact meaning for a quoted symbol in lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, common-lisp

```
(message "%s" 'abc)
(message "%s" "abc")
```

I found that both the former expression will be the same result( in emacs ).
Although I know this is not really a property example to show my question.

Could you explain more about what's the exact meaning for a quoted symbol?
And the what does the quoted symbol return? A string representation of a variable name or something else?

Comment: Have you read the WP article?  If not, it may be a helpful starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming\)

Comment: Also `M-: (info "(elisp) Symbols") RET` (or http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbols.html )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbols in Lisp can serve several purposes, including, but not limited to:

- a simple data type for representing anything atomic that the other simple data types cannot or should not -- thus similar to enumerations in C-family languages. For instance, a function MakeWidget may take an argument Size, the possible values of which are 'small, 'medium, and 'large. Symbols used this way need not be declared, though there are simple means to limit the range of values if need be.
- variable name
- function name

A quoted symbol returns the symbol itself.

A symbol can be printed, and, as as you saw, prints just like a string.

So, why would you want to use a symbol when you can just as easily use a string?

- the name of a symbol doesn't change, so it uses less memory than a string
- a symbol can be used to store a reference to a function you want to call in a non-trivial way. A typical example is applying a function to a list -- e.g., if square is a properly defined function, then:

`(apply #'square '(1 2 3 4))`

returns

```
(1 4 9 16)
```

There are other uses for symbols not mentioned here, but hopefully this gives you a good start.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest answer is: a symbol is unique within the system while a string is not.
The following test will make the point clear:

```
? (eq 'abc 'abc) 
T 
? (eq "abc" "abc")
NIL
```

A symbol is *interned* only once in the system. All further references point to the same object. In other words, a symbol is a singleton and comparing two symbols is just a matter of comparing pointers. So it is faster. This is not the case with strings. In the above example, the two instances of the string `"abc"` are two objects.

Answer (score 2):

A quote simply turns off evaluation on the form that you've quoted.  Exactly what that does will change depending on what lisp you're using and what you've quoted.

Evaluating a symbol generally involves looking up the value for that symbol.  Quoting a symbol will turn that lookup off, which means that the symbol itself is returned.  Printing a symbol prints the symbol's name, which is why you get the same output from your two examples.

Answer (score 1):

A quoted symbol evaluates to the symbol itself.

A symbol has a name (among possibly other things like a value). If you print a symbol, its name gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what is written above:

Both strings and symbols can be "unique" (what was said above was incorrect). They are objects with identity.

`(setq foo "abc")`

`(setq bar foo)`

`(eq foo bar)`

The values of variables `foo` and `bar` are the same (unique) string.

The reason that `(eq "abc" "abc")` is non-`nil` is that the Lisp reader produces two different string objects from those two literal string expressions. When the Lisp reader encounters just `abc`, on the other hand, it reads it as a symbol name. It (as was said correctly above) interns a symbol with that name the first time and looks the symbol name up thereafter.

Wrt evaluation:

- Strings are self-quoting; that is, they evaluate to themselves. Most symbols are not (`t` and `nil` are notable exceptions).
- During evaluation, a symbol is looked up to get either (a) its associated function, if it is used in context as a function or (b) its associated value, if it is used in context as a variable.

In `(abc xyz)`:

- The symbol `abc` is used in context as a function, so its function is looked up and used (the value of its function "cell").
- The symbol `xyz` is used in context as a variable, so its variable value is looked up and used (the value of its variable "cell").

IOW, symbols in Emacs Lisp have two "cells" or meanings: (a) as a function, (b) as a variable.  A given symbol might be undefined as a variable or as a function, or it might have both kinds of definition.

Finally, to say that `(message "%s" "abc")` has the same value as `(message "%s" 'abc)` is a misstatement, in terms of what you meant.  They both return the same *value*, which is `nil`, and they both have the same *effect*, which is to print `abc`.